# Why RIGHT JOINs do not work in request with products data?

Tags: mysql

I have 5 related tables of products and related data in mysql 8 :

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
`id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
I=>Inactive',
`sale_price` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
...
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),


CREATE TABLE `products_cities` (
`id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`product_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
`city_id` smallint unsigned NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),



CREATE TABLE `cities` (
`id` smallint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`address` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`postal_code` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`country` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`region` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`geo_lat` decimal(16,7) NOT NULL,
`geo_lon` decimal(16,7) NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)


CREATE TABLE `discount_product` (
`id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`product_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
`discount_id` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL,
...
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),


CREATE TABLE `discounts` (
`id` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
...
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
```

I need to get list of products filtered by cities.region (that part works ok) and I use INNER JOIN in first 2 relations,
but I need to show products if no related discount rows found and I write 2 RIGHT JOINs:

```
SELECT products.id, products.title, products.sale_price,
cities.address AS citiy_address, cities.id AS citiy_id,
discounts.id as discounts_id, discounts.name as discounts_name
    FROM products INNER JOIN
    products_cities on products_cities.product_id = products.id INNER JOIN
    cities on cities.id = products_cities.city_id RIGHT JOIN  -- ??
    discount_product on discount_product.product_id = products.id RIGHT JOIN  -- ??
    discounts on discounts.id = discount_product.discount_id
    WHERE cities.region = 'Aberdeen City'
```

I expected that discounts.id as discounts_id, discounts.name as discounts_name would be null, but products are excluded ?

What is wrong in my request ?

Comment: I think you have used RIGHT JOIN when you should have used LEFT JOIN. You should review the definitions of those types of joins, which should be in any book or tutorial on SQL.

Comment: @Bill Karwin Sir, I'm sorry to bother you with this off-topic comment as I could not contact you otherwise. I found in your book `sql antipatterns vol.1` on page 176 , the `derived-table-no-duplicates.sql` code would not get the correct result if multiple `product_id` with the same latest `date_reported` value exist. Here is the db-fiddle link: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3QjYFsX17WgB2mvBuoqbsa/2 In the example, product_id 2 will get the bug_id 5999 which is actually associated with product_id 3.

Comment: @blabla_bingo, Thanks, I'll be glad to look at the example. Could I ask you to post book errata as a new topic on my publisher's DevTalk site here: https://forum.devtalk.com/tags/c/community/pragprog-customers/85/book-sql-antipatterns-volume-1 Stack Overflow gets pretty finicky about off-topic conversations in the comments.

Comment: @Bill Karwin, Certainly. I've posted there and it is waiting for approval from moderator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your query lies in the combination of INNER JOINs and RIGHT JOINs. When you use INNER JOIN, it only returns rows that have matching rows in both joined tables. When you use RIGHT JOIN, it returns all rows from the right table (discount_product and discounts in your case) and the matched rows from the left table (products in your case). If there is no match in the left table, the result will still contain a row from the right table with NULL values for columns from the left table.

```
SELECT 
    products.id, 
    products.title, 
    products.sale_price,
    cities.address AS citiy_address, 
    cities.id AS citiy_id,
    discounts.id as discounts_id, 
    discounts.name as discounts_name
FROM 
    products
INNER JOIN 
    products_cities ON products_cities.product_id = products.id
INNER JOIN 
    cities ON cities.id = products_cities.city_id
LEFT JOIN 
    discount_product ON discount_product.product_id = products.id
LEFT JOIN 
    discounts ON discounts.id = discount_product.discount_id
WHERE 
    cities.region = 'Aberdeen City';
```